# Make Quickblox group dialog chat read-only

Tags: android, quickblox

I have a requirement to make a group dialog in QuickBlox read-only after some messages are exchanged. Is there anything which quickblox supports?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such tools but it can be performed on the application's side. You will need to add any custom parameter and change it when the dialogue should be read-only and before the message is sent this parameter should be checked first.